# Filtering an array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i have a script which takes data from a database and displays it on a page.

It sorts the rows by an id number, and displays them in that order

heres the script

```
// get the info from the db 
$sql = "SELECT showtime, html FROM showfeed ORDER BY showtime ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

// while there are rows to be fetched...
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
   // echo data
   echo $list['html'] . "<hr />";
} // end while
```

what I want to do is filter that data so that if the ID number of a row is less than a given number than it won't be displayed.  And if it is greater than a certain number it will be displayed normally.

Comment: What kind of id are you talking about? If you want an id for every insertion in the database, use an auto_incremented primary key.

Comment: Could you please formulate clearly what you want? Less than a certain number? And greater than a certain number? Same number?

Comment: They database already has ID's, that not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ID is a field in your table:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, showtime, html FROM showfeed ORDER BY showtime ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

// while there are rows to be fetched...
$targetID = 120;
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
   // echo data
   if ($list['id'] < $targetID) continue;
   echo $list['html'] . "<hr />";
} // end while
```

However, if this would work for you, then probably better to change your query to

```
$sql = "SELECT showtime, html FROM showfeed WHERE id > 120 ORDER BY showtime ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Comment: Sweet this works, I used the second script.  Thanks everyone else as well!

Answer (score 4):

Do it in the database query.

```
SELECT ... WHERE id > $certainNumber ...
```

If, for whatever reason, you want to do it in PHP:

```
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($list['id'] < $certainNumber) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter sql query (the word "array" is not right here).

you have to filter the query using sql instead of your application
Something like that

```
SELECT showtime, html FROM showfeed WHERE ID > ?? AND ID < ?? ORDER BY showtime ASC
```